# How to create lines under the uicollectionview cell ? (iOS)

Tags: ios, user-interface, uicollectionview, interface-builder

How to create a line under the UICollectionView Cell like this ?[image]

Comment: Seems to be a `UITableViewCell`. And seems to be a cell separator.

Comment: Best thing you can do is to create a custom cell and add a UIView at the bottom of it that's around 1 pixel in height. Just so you can customise it all you like

Comment: I think it's a parameter of UITableView and not of UICollectionView.

Comment: @Larme It scroll horizontal , i thinks it is a uicollectionview cell.

Comment: For me, that's a `UITableView` embeded in a `UICollectionViewCell`

Comment: use a UIView with 0.5 height constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making your own custom separator view, it would be an easy and better approach. The view would be of 1px height, with bottom constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You can use separator from the UITableView. This one cannot be customized a lot. ie: You cannot change the height of the separator.

If you want more control over the separator you can add a view at the bottom of your table view cell.